# What is the difference between \clearpage and \newpage?

Tags: page, clearpage

I have a .tex document, with two subsections: `subsection1` and `subsection2`, but I wouldn't like to cut any subsection in the middle. So my question is: What's the difference between `\clearpage` and `\newpage`, and what option is the best for my problem?

Comment: Welcome. // Kindly have a look e.g. into https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Manual_page_formatting or any other good book on Latex.